# Web Scraping with login but no csrf

Tags: python, asp.net, authentication, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website for the company that I work with. But inspecting the page after login, I couldn't find any csrf_token. Instead I found a Authentication key....

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from requests.api import head
from scrapy.http import headers
from scrapy.http.headers import Headers

URL = 'https://pgtindustries.kminnovations.net/Apps/Login/UserLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fApps%2fDefault.aspx'
my_login = '97295'
my_password = 'password'    
ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36'
origin = 'https://pgtindustries.kminnovations.net'
referer = 'https://pgtindustries.kminnovations.net/Apps/Login/UserLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fApps%2fDefault.aspx'

HEADERS = {'User-Agent':ua, 'origin': origin, 'referer': referer }

s = requests.session()

auth = s.get(URL).cookies['.KMIAUTH_PGT']
print(auth)

login_payload = {
    'login': my_login,
    'password': my_password,
    '__VIEWSTATE': auth
}

login_req = s.post(URL, headers=HEADERS, data=login_payload)

print(login_req)
```

[image]

the website that I'm trying is:

https://pgtindustries.kminnovations.net/Apps/Login/UserLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fApps%2fDefault.aspx

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to do access it without a csrf_token? or using the other type of authentication

Comment: the csrf token is not authentication... it just ties the session to the form to help prevent faking the form.  (should be combo of hidden field in form and http-only cookie) You should probably use Selenium for this.  That way you can just let the browser do it's thing.